# MS CRM 2011 (online) Outlook client, Unable to persist "maximum number of lines in compact mode"

Tags: dynamics-crm

Accessing CRM via Outlook, we have the following scenario:

1. We are looking at opportunity entities
2. We are looking at a personal view of opportunities
3. We have the reading pane set to show on the right
4. This causes the opportunity list to “show in compact mode” on the
   left
5. How many columns display for each opportunity on the left is
   determined by an outlook view setting (View tab | View Settings |
   Columns button and setting the ‘Maximum number of lines in compact
   mode’)
6. The default for this setting seems to be 3
7. We want it to be 7
8. We can set it to 7 and the view reflects this but only while the
   view display persists
9. As soon as we navigate away from the view, the setting reverts back
   to 3

Is there any way for outlook to remember this setting for our personal view?

Comment: why was this migrated to superuser?

Comment: Because this is not a developer question but rather admin/superuser question - it belongs here and not on stackoverflow